# Excel Conditional Formatting Colors are "Bleeding" Into Cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I've been trying to figure out this issue for a few hours now and can't figure it out.

I've created a table that has some conditional formatting of rows. I'm using the formula based rule type and applying it to all the cells in the row.

In the formula i'm putting =$G$10="xxxx". In the "Applies to" section it looks like =$A$10:$P$10 or $P$11 for rows that have multiple rows combined.

The problem i'm experiencing with a few of these are that they "bleed" into rows that aren't in the range listed for the rule. This isn't happening on every line or even rule, nor is it exclusive to single or multiple line rules. I have no idea what is going on with this; any help would be much appreciated!

[image: symptom]

[image: Rules]

Comment: Did you by chance copy/paste the conditional formatting across rows? I'm guessing your use of merged cells across rows might require some extra caution when it comes to conditional formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The problem i'm experiencing with a few of these are that they "bleed" into rows that aren't in the range listed for the rule.

However it seems that you not looking at all the Formatting Conditions in the worksheet. Try this:

1. Open the [*Conditional Formatting Rules Manager*] dialog box,
2. and in the option [*Show formatting rules for:*] select "*This
   Worksheet*"

Then you'll see all the cells actually affected by "*Conditional Formatting*"

Then clear the formatting conditions for all the cells that should not have it, and be careful when copying cell in worksheet with conditional formatting.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what was going on because I had 5 rules per line and it was getting muddy trying to make sense of it all. So, I started from scratch and was more meticulous about the rules, which seemed to solve the problem.